From Observablehq notebook connect to an AppsScript webapp with authentication
Within Observablehq notebooks, I can easily contact services with fetch(url).
Everything ok with public services.
I would like to access a Google AppsScript deployed as webapp (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) requiring authentication.
I found on Observablehq examples (https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/working-with-apis-remote-files) accessing GitHub or AWS S3, but I can't seem to be able to adapt to a GAS webapp.
Is it possible to obtain a token for the notebook to use?
What I probably want is: from the the notebook, popup the Google authorization prompt so the user can grant access, but I have no idea how this might work: let's say I'm trying to understand OAuth, but it confuses me quite a bit.
Is the whole thing even possible?
